# MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue >1

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Good evening,

I've been busy with Mongoosejs + Node.js, and I've got the following error at the moment.

```
[Login-01][ERROR] MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue >1 field in obj: { 
_events: {}, _posts: { save: [] }, _pres: { save: [] }, _doc: { _id: 
ObjectId('537a652e88d1ff281aa9ce95'), name: "Diamondo25", banResetDate: null, 
creationDate: new Date(1400530222052), female: null, isAdmin: false, __v: 0, password: 
"---", salt: "---" }, _maxListeners: 0, errors: null, isNew: false, $__: { fullPath:
 null, ownerDocument: null, activePaths: { stateNames: [ "require", "modify", "init",
 "default" ], states: { require: {}, modify: {}, init: { _id: true, name: true, 
banResetDate: true, creationDate: true, female: true, isAdmin: true, __v: true, 
password: true, salt: true }, default: {} }, paths: { _id: "init", name: "init", 
banResetDate: "init", creationDate: "init", female: "init", isAdmin:"init", __v: 
"init", password: "init", salt: "init" } }, scope: null, wasPopulated: false, 
populated: null, populate: null, _id: null, getters: {}, version: null, inserting: 
null, removing: null, adhocPaths: null, validationError: null, saveError: null, 
shardval: null, selected: null, strictMode: true } }
```

I cannot reproduce the error in a simple variant of the triggering code (which is ran inside a callback of a TCP packet).

```
function test() {
    var document = FindDocumentByCutoffId(Character, 1400622496);
    console.log(document);
    console.log(document.remove());
}
wait.launchFiber(test);
```

`character` inside the callback of `SetHandler` is the same object as the one that is logged by the code above.

```
PacketHandler.SetHandler(0x0017, function (pSocket, pReader) {
    var id = pReader.ReadUInt32();
    var character = FindDocumentByCutoffId(Character, id, {
        account: pSocket.account,
        worldId: pSocket.state.worldId
    });

    if (!character) {
        pSocket.Disconnect();
        return;
    }
    wait.forMethod(character, 'remove');
});

global.FindDocumentByCutoffId = function (pSchema, pDocumentId, pFilterAdditions) {
    var filter = pFilterAdditions || {};
    pDocumentId = pDocumentId.toString(16);

    // Get all rows
    var rows = wait.forMethod(pSchema, 'find', '_id', filter);

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (String(rows[i]._id).indexOf(pDocumentId) == 0) {
            return wait.forMethod(pSchema, 'findById', rows[i]._id);
        }
    }

    return null;
};
```

**Edit:** Wait a second. Why does it print the Account object inside the error? O_o

Comment: Can you edit your question to better format that error message so that it's not all on one line?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Changed the error text. Also, note that it shows the Account info instead of the Character info (username and pass = inside Account object)

Answer (score 4):

this error can occur if you're doing an illegal operation, such as trying to update a FindOne operation:

```
accounts.findOne({"user.email":options.user.email}, options, {upsert:false}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    callback(null, 'updated thank you');
    });
```

Will raise the exception, when the correct method would be:

```
accounts.update({"user.email":options.user.email}, options, {upsert:false}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    callback(null, 'updated thank you');
    });
```